# Incorrect results when using "in" operator with Pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have two dataframes df1 contains 100K rows and df2 contains 6 million rows. I want to fix values for 'SoftDel???' column in df1 when 'id' matches in df2. code is working but results are wrong.

I have completed this task using merge and results are satisfactory but want to know why below is producing wrong results?

`for x, y in df1.iterrows():

    if y['id'] in df2['id']:
        df1.loc[x,'SoftDel???'] = 'No'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`y['id']` is a float. But, `df2['id']` is a series. The `in` operator is not designed to work with a series as one of the arguments.

Comment: Thanks but I tried this and throw error:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: @AnkitSaini Never mind, it's a simple error. Check my edit.

Comment: @coldspeed: 
`for x, y in df1.iterrows(): 
 if df2['id'].isin(y['id']).any():
  df1.loc[x, 'SoftDel???'] = "No"`
when used above got this: "TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [int]"

and when use this 
`for x, y in df1.iterrows(): 
 if y['id'].isin(df2['id']).any():
  df1.loc[x, 'SoftDel???'] = "No"`
got : AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isin'

Comment: @AnkitSaini `if df2['id'].isin([y['id']]).any()` <--- extra square brackets

Comment: @ColdSpeed: Thanks It worked. But took more than hour so think Merge approach is better and can be done same thing in less than 10 min. 
Thanks Again for your Help!!!